# What makes it a deadlock and how to make it deadlock free?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, locking, deadlock

I am having problems knowing how the code satisfies the conditions for deadlock? And is there any suggestions or strategies to help make the code deadlock free?

```
Thread1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock1.acquire();
        lock2.acquire();
        CriticalSection();
        lock2.release();
        lock1.release();
    }
}

Thread2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock2.acquire();
        lock3.acquire();
        CriticalSection();
        lock3.release();
        lock2.release();
    }
}

Thread3()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock3.acquire();
        lock2.acquire();
        CriticalSection();
        lock1.release();
        lock3.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock happens when a process attempts to acquire a resource A while holding resource B, and another process attempts to acquire B while holding A. So, in your program thread 2 and thread3 can crate a deadlock because they both try to acquire lock2 and lock3. If they acquire these resources in the same order, the program will be deadlock safe. For instance if both threads acquire lock2 before lock3, then no process can try to acquire lock2 while holding lock3. However in your program, thread2 acquires 2 before 3, and thread3 acquires 3 before 2, creating a potential deadlock.